# Software to generate geometric shapes

Tags: windows, images

I am looking for a software for Windows such that

1. able to make transformations (rotation, continuously changing one shape to another, etc)
2. able to make 3D objects
3. with good quality

better you look the examples:

[image: Example1] [image: Example2] [image: Example3]

(I am a mathematician so software can include technical stuffs)

Comment: Are you looking for a separate app – or rather for a library so you can integrate this in your own app?

Comment: separate app ,i want this app to make gif and images only

Comment: software for windows

Comment: Does the application require programming stuff (so, you need to write codes)?